# React Native iOS, How to call reload of RCTBridge use my own RCTBridgeDelegate.loadSource method

Tags: react-native

I overrode RCTBridgeDelegate and loadSource method. 
When I first initialized RCTBridge, it loaded source correctly using my overridden loadSource method, but when I called reload from RCTBridge, it errors out with error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xhJ4.png)

I'd tried to debug this, and found that after RCTBridge initialized the first time, the delegate was not saved, and when i called reload method, RN used the default javascript loader.

Is there another way to solve this?

React Native version: 0.44.0
Platform:
MacOS, iPhone 6, monitor